# Navigate to a page only on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that needs to be filled out in order to navigate to another page. However, this page needs to be hidden (even if I get the url and paste it to another tab is should display 404 and of course not be included in google search). So, the only way one can navigate to it is by filling out the form. How can I achieve this by changing the URL of the page that contains the form and the page we want to navigate to? I am using PHP/JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: Does the form need to filled out with specific data for the page to show, or will any old junk do the trick? If the later, then the existing answers are fine. If the former you need to give more details to get a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the form was filled in and redirect them otherwise to your 404 page. Place the following script in your page that needs to be hidden:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // Default 404 redirect OR:
         header("Location: 404.php"); // Custom 404 page
         exit;
    }
?>
```

Change `'submit'` to the name of your submit button. You can choose between a default 404 header (the first option) or a custom page (second option). If you setup your `.htaccess` file correctly, you should be able to use the default 404 header anyway. You can also replace `404.php` with any page, for example the page with your form. If you don't want a page to be indexed by search engines, you can create a file called `robots.txt` and use the following content:

```
Disallow: /private_file.php
```

Change the file name to your own file, ofcourse. Please note that search engines do not *have* to follow rules set in the `robots.txt` file.

Comment: You can do `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` directly. The redirect seems weird.

Comment: @Halcyon Very true, I edited the answer.

Comment: Plus, always add `exit;` after header to avoid further code execution.

Comment: @ble Did this work for you? If so, don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: @KevinVoorn it seems like it doesn't find the 404 page. should I have something like "header("Location: error-404.php");" after header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")?

Comment: @ble Well, if you don't have a custom 404 page it will use the browser default 404 page. If you have a custom one setup, this should work but I will edit my answer real quick.

Comment: @KevinVoorn my problem is that the ajax post request expects json back and that's why my 404.php is not displayed. Should I redirect to 404.php through JavaScript?

Comment: @ble you could try that yes

Comment: Another happy ending ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have the page accept only `POST` data, and if the data is missing return a 404 instead.